# Best way to implement design in Android Application?

Tags: android, user-interface, nine-patch

I am currently developing an Android Application for a company who are set on having this type of design and targeting Hires devices however I have found that this is very difficult to do and on some hires devices buttons start to stretch.

Screen design here: https://skitch.com/aaronwardle/r7kwa/screen

A few people have recommended making the buttons into Nine Patch PNG files which help with the various screen layouts.

Should I try and get a new app design for this project, which fits all screens using standard controls, or do you think this is achievable?

Looking at stats the most common devices are small screen ones, so creating this application may have a limited audience.

If any one has any pointers on what I could do, i.e. could I make this for hi res screens and within the application have a different layout for smaller screens?

Thanks Aaron!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too generic to give a simple and quick answer. Furthermore, the layout you want to make is complex and very non-native-looking which complicates matters. Please make sure you read and understand the official docs on the subject from [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). There is no replacement for that...

The main points that come to mind from that document are:

1. the `<supports-screens>` manifest item
2. Resource directory qualifiers for screen size and density. Appending stuff such as `-small` or `-portrait` allows you to create resources that are loaded only on a particular screen aspect, size or DPI. For example, you can create bigger images for bigger screens, or change the layout XMLs for portrait or landscape
3. Use 9-patch images to scale up rectangles (buttons).

Best practices (as recommended by Google):

1. Use wrap_content, fill_parent, or the dp unit, instead of absolute pixels
2. Avoid AbsoluteLayout
3. Do not use hard-coded pixel values in your code
4. Use density and/or size-specific resources

I know my answer is a bit generic, but then again, so is your question...

Comment: Thanks for your response and you are right my question is too vague. I will read through the documents and also I am trying out 9-patch images in a sample project.  Is it not common in Android Apps to have the keyboard always visible on large screens? If you could give me some pointers to what is not standard that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 9 patch png and also will have to make some changes in the manifest file, to make it screen resolution free. These are very less changes in the manifest file so would not be a trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so do you think the linked design above is possible if I was to create 9 patch png files? I did try and make a number button 9 patch but it did not quite work I suspect that I need to remove the text from the button and add that in via the layout / code?

Comment: just with png it will not work. You have to make a proper xml as per the need. Firstly focus on making it work on any screen in the emulator, later with just minor changes in the manifest file and png buttons it will become screen resolution independent. If you are facing any problem in getting any specific desired result, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9 patch images as well as to design application for different resolutions, you can create different layouts for landscape and portrait.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so could I for exmaple use this layout for a hires screen device and then supply a different layout for lowres screens where say for example the keypad popups up into the view instead of being there all the time?

Comment: You can do this via putting layouts in layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-ldpi.